# .on delegated event without click

Tags: jquery, events

I'm working with a third party plugin.
And I need to change some css.

I can't rely on click or other mouse or keyboard event.

I need that when "x" element exist on the screen, it receive some classes.

```
$(document).on('ready load', '.form-row', function() {
    $(this).addClass('radio');
});
```

I know that someone will copy the jquery documentation saying about load event.

But I need when some element is inserted into the DOM it receives this class.

I already did this in older version of jquery and i don't understand why now it will not work

Comment: I don't think this has ever worked. There is no load event on regular elements. You can listen to mutation events

Comment: You can't delegate the `ready` or `load` events as they only fire once, and not on child elements. Check in the plugin if an event is raised when the element you need is added to the DOM, if there is you can add an event hook to it.

Comment: Depending on your compatibility requirements, you can use [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) you can listen to DOM changes, for a specific HTML node, or the entire DOM...

- **Note:** You should check for browsers compatibility of the MutationObserver to make sure it meets your needs.

Here is a sample code to see how it works:

```
// select the target node
var target = document.querySelector('#some-id');

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation.type);
  });    
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);

// later, you can stop observing
observer.disconnect();
```

Comment: And make sure to look at the Browser compatibility if you are going to use this since it is limited to modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

try `DOMNodeInserted`, you can target a particular element where the insert will take place (`.container`) :-

```js
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', '.container', function() {
    $('.form-row').addClass('radio');
});


$('<div></div>', { 'class':'form-row' }).appendTo('.container');
```

```css
.container{
    background-color:blue;
    padding:20px;
}

.radio{
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```